# Copy files from remote desktop using different login

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop

I use remote desktop to connect to a computer that has files I want.  While on the remote computer, I would like to copy the files into the C:\ drive on my local computer.  I can see my C:\ drive on the remote computer, but when I try to copy over files, I get a dialog saying I don't have permission to perform that action.

I have to log in to the remote computer using generic credentials, so I'm not sure if the problem is that the logins between the two computers are different.  I tried editing the permissions on my C:\ drive to give full permissions to the generic account, but that didn't help.

I used to have Windows 7, and I didn't have any trouble.  I never changed any of the remote desktop settings from their defaults.  But I've just had to switch to a new computer with Windows 10 and I can't get it to work.  Is there something simple I can do to make it work like it used to?

Comment: RDP will let you copy "outside the window" by copying files from an explorer window in your RDP session, then minimizing the RDP window, and pasting into an explorer window on the local c:\ drive. The key here is that the user performing the Paste must have permissions to the directory, but the RDP logged-in user (who copies) does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you use system built-in Remote Desktop Connection client, please make sure that below options are selected:
1.  Run “**mstsc**” to open Remote Desktop Connection.
2.  Select **Local Resources** tab, **Local devices and resources** section, select **Clipboard**.
3.  Click **More**.
4.  Expand **Drivers**, select your C drive.
5.  Save the change and check the result.

Best Regards,
Eve Wang